# Element Checkbox got its label always to the left and needs a link

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

How can I change the positions of checkbox and label and how to implement a link into the label?

```
$acceptGTC = new Element\Checkbox('AGBs');
$acceptGTC->setLabel('I Accept the GTC (<a href="some link">show it</a>).');
$this->add($acceptGTC);
```

regards
n00n

meanwhile: 
I tried to overwrite the view helper for checkboxes.

copied 
*/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/View/Helper/FormCheckbox.php
to 
*/module/Application/src/Application/View/Helper/FormCheckbox.php

added to module.config.php
'viewhelpers' => array('checkbox'=>'Application\View\Helper'),

But it still uses the original one... 
Do I have to tell zend to use my FormCheckbox?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know the way you are rendering your Zend_Form_Element, but in order to enhance the rendering as you want you should build a custom decorator, and add it to this element.

You should read the Zend documentation on Zend_Form_Decorators, everything is quite well explained and should lead you to a fancy solution.